# Why (and how) to choose $a$ in $\varrho(t):=a 1_{[0,1]}(t)\exp\left(\frac 1{t^2-1}\right)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varrho(|x|)\;dx=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $$\varrho(t):=\begin{cases}\alpha\exp\left(\frac 1{t^2-1}\right)&\text{, if }t\in [0,1]\\ 0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Why (and how) can we choose $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varrho\left(|x|\right)\;d\lambda_n(x)=1$$ (where $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure and $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm)?

Comment: Take $\alpha^{-1}=\|\varrho\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: @Nicolas No. Note that $\|\varrho\|_{L^1}=1$.

Comment: Arg! I wanted to write what @Tryss answered, but I was lazy and I wrote a wrong thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **can** choose $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varrho(|x|) dx =1$$

Because

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varrho(|x|) dx = \alpha \int_{B(0,1)}  \exp \left( \frac{1}{|x|^2-1} \right) dx $$

And consider

$$I =\int_{B(0,1)}  \exp \left( \frac{1}{|x|^2-1} \right)dx $$

$I$ is well defined and different from 0, so you just need to choose $\alpha = I^{-1}$

Now if you want the exact value of $I$, it's another story, but do you really need it?

Comment: There are some errors in your second integral (second equation).

Comment: No, I don't need the exactly value of $I$. Thanks!

Comment: @0xbadf00d : thanks for noticing, it's obviously a typo